# Writing out 'AND' and 'OR' in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

How do you write out 'AND' and 'OR' in LINQ.
Ive tried the 'AND' keyword as well as '&&' and a ','.

I have also googled it and havent come across anything that helps.

Any help will be highly appreciated
Thanks

EDIT:

```
    int[] moreScores = new int[]{12,12,45,45,87,96};
int[] scores = new int[] { 97, 92, 81, 60 };
        // Define the query expression.
        IEnumerable<int> scoreQuery =
            from score in scores
    and moreScores
            where score > 80
            select score;
```

Comment: Could you give an example of what you want to accomplish?

Comment: Normally, as `&&` and `||`. Give us an example.

Comment: what language are you using ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it depends on the langauge you use

in **C#**, `&&` for *AND* and `||` for *OR* 
in **VB**, `AND` for *AND* and `OR` for *OR*

now, what language are you using?

**UPDATE 1**

you want to join the two tables first right?

`UNION` method excludes duplicates from the return set.

```
IEnumerable<int> scoreQuery =  from score in (scores.Union(moreScores))
                               where score > 80
                               select score;
```

[image]

Comment: In VB.NET, I would recommend using `AndAlso` / `OrElse` as the equivalents of C#'s `&&` / `||` (because they are short-circuiting, unlike `And` / `Or`).

Answer (score 2):

If you give us correct example, you should use Union, not AND:

```
    IEnumerable<int> scoreQuery =
    from score in scores.Union(moreScores)
    where score > 80
    select score;
```

Comment: Thank you, missed this moment

Answer (score 1):

You cannot simply query two different arrays by putting AND in between them. Try the following code:

```
var moreScores = new int[] { 12, 12, 45, 45, 87, 96 };
var scores = new int[] { 97, 92, 81, 60 };
var scoreQueryResults =
    from score in (scores.Union(moreScores))
    where score > 80
    select score;
```

Also some generic example for Linq.

```
var list = new List<string>();
// ... add some items

// Searching for the strings that starts with J AND ends K
// Method Chain Format
var results1 = list.Where(item => item.StartsWith("J") && item.EndsWith("K"));
// Query Format
var results2 = from item in list
                where item.StartsWith("J") && item.EndsWith("K")
                select item;

// Searching for the strings that starts with J OR K
// Method Chain Format
var results3 = list.Where(item => item.StartsWith("J") || item.StartsWith("K"));
// Query Format
var results4 = from item in list
                where item.StartsWith("J") || item.StartsWith("K")
                select item;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to write something like this...

```
int[] moreScores = new int[]{12,12,45,45,87,96}; 
int[] scores = new int[] { 97, 92, 81, 60 };         
// Define the query expression.         
IEnumerable<int> scoreQuery = from score in scores.Union(moreScores) 
                              where score > 80             
                              select score;
```

Answer (score 1):

Linq doesen't work like that, you first have to combine your two sets.

```
var allScores = scores.Concat(morescores);
```

Then you could do,

```
var scoreGreaterTham80 = allScores.Where(s => s > 80);
```

---

if you wanted to exclude duplicates between `scores` and `morescores` use `Union` instead of `Concat`.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is [`Concat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx) because I assume with *scores* you generally don't want to exclude anything, which `Union` will do.

```
int[] moreScores = new int[] { 12, 12, 45, 45, 87, 96 };
int[] scores = new int[] { 97, 92, 81, 60 };

IEnumerable<int> scoreQuery = from score in moreScores.Concat(scores)
                              where score > 80
                              select score;
```